# Ruby array to an indexed hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I often find myself building lookup tables in Ruby, generally to cache some expensive computation or to build something I'm passing to a view. I figure there must be a short, readable idiom for this, but we couldn't think of one. For example, suppose I want to start with

```
[65, 66, 67, ...]
```

and end up with

```
{65 => "A", 66 => "B", 67 => "C", ...}
```

The not-quite-pretty-enough idioms we could think of include:

```
array = (65..90).to_a

array.inject({}) {|hash, key| hash[key]=key.chr; hash}
{}.tap {|hash| array.each {|key| hash[key] = key.chr}}
Hash[array.zip(array.map{|key| key.chr})]
```

But all of these are a little painful: hard to read, easy to mess up, not clear in intent. Surely Ruby (or some Rails helper) has some nice magic for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most idiomatic way from Ruby 2.1 onwards is to use `.to_h` since it can be called on a block like so:

```
(65..90).map { |i| [i, i.chr] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 24):

What about

```
 Hash[(65..90).map { |i| [i, i.chr] }]
```

I think this is quite obvious and self-explaining. Also, I don't there exists a much simpler way to solve this rather specific task, Ruby unfortunately doesn't have something comparable to dict comprehension in Python. If you want, you can use the [Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/) gem, which includes something close:

```
require 'facets'
(65..90).mash { |i| [i, i.chr] }
```

Comment: Wow. I never would have guessed that a bunch of array pairs would have been interpreted in that way. I would have expected it to turn into {[65, "A"] => [66, "B"], [67, "C"] => [68, "D"], ...}. That scares me a little, but I'll still use it. Thanks!

Comment: @William: You can use [`Hash.[]`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/%5B%5D/class) in two forms: `Hash[key, value, key, value, ...]` or `Hash[[[key, value], [key, value], ... ]]` with the inner array representing any enumerable yielding key/value pairs. Remember that in Ruby, there's more than one to do it :P Also, I added another suggestion using facets.

Comment: Sure enough. Right there in the docs. Thanks! I'll definitely check out Facets as well; looks great.

Comment: If ever my `associate` proposal makes it through (see [ruby-core:33683]), you could write `array.associate(&:chr)` in this case.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: That'd be really nice. Actually I tried `.mash(&:chr)` because I though this was how it worked. Good luck with that proposal :)

Comment: @William: By the way, I just noticed that your own example `Hash[array.zip(array.map{|key| key.chr})]` actually makes use of the list of pairs thing :)

Comment: @NiklasB.: A case of two errors canceling each other: I thought that zip returned the flattened form. Ah, the joys of learning a new language!